# Animations trigger before page loads

Tags: javascript, html, animation, preloader, animate.css

I created a website that uses [animate.css](https://animate.style/) to animate elements. But the problem is that the animations trigger before the page loads. I avoid using the delay property provided by [animate.css](https://animate.style/) as the page may take different loading times to load on different devices. Please suggest something.

Also, I'm using a pre-loader for the website if that helps.

Comment: Show us some code please.

Answer (score 0):

You can show full screen gif animation (loader) untill site loading. And using js:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    document.getElementById('loader').hidden = true;
});
```